# NetLogo BehaviorSpace does not recognize initial settings on patches by mouse-down

Tags: netlogo, cellular-automata, behaviorspace

I have a patch lattice with an arbitrary configuration of states whose initial setting is done manually using `mouse-down` primitive.
While running BehaviorSpace, it moves the arbitrary setting starting with a random configuration of states.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're asking, so here are two possibilities.

#### If you *want* BehaviorSpace to use a random state for patches

```
to setup
  clear-all
  if behaviorspace-run-number != 0 [ ; if BehaviorSpace is running
    ask patches [
      ; use whatever random state you want...
      set pcolor one-of [ black white ]
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Another option is the use the "Setup commands" of the BehaviorSpace dialog box:

[image]

#### If you want to run BehaviorSpace experiments with state previouly entered with the mouse by a user...

...then things are a little trickier. The basic idea is to save that state to a file and then load that file and initialize the state when the model runs from BehaviorSpace.

In the example below, I do this using the [`csv` extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html).

Keep in mind that taking `pcolor` to represent the patches' state is just for the sake of example; it could be any other kind of state.

```
extensions [ csv ]

to setup
  clear-all
  if behaviorspace-run-number != 0 [
    (foreach (sort patches) (first csv:from-file "patch-states.csv") [
      ask ?1 [ set pcolor ?2 ]
    ])
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to draw ; call this from a "forever" button
  if mouse-down? [
    ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor [ set pcolor white ]
  ]
end

to save ; call this from a regular button
  let patch-states map [ [ pcolor ] of ? ] sort patches
  (csv:to-file "patch-states.csv" (list patch-states))
end
```

I realize that some parts of the code above can be tricky to understand (i.e., the use of `foreach` and `map`). Feel free to ask follow up questions if there is a specific part that you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, it is solved now! using extensions[csv] and a csv file where state categories correspond to numbers, then setup in BehaviorSpace; it is now running well.